# Make edittext view Html.fromHtml text

Tags: android, html, kotlin

I am trying to make a edittext view an HTML string, but it doesn't work. Though it works with textViews.

This is what I want:

Hey **David**

This is what I get:

Hey David

My HTML string:
[image]

The HTML string is a picture because if you write any HTML in stackoverflow it will be formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way and it's working fine:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>hey</b>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}else{
        editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>hey</b>"));
  }
```

Comment: It works fine on single line edittexts but not on multilined ones. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Sorry, it actually worked. It was just something with my XML.